# generate html file and download it with php

Tags: php, html, download

First goal: Create an index.html file and create a link to download the generated file

The issue here is when i click to generate new file the downloaded file is always the same and isnt updated

the variable `$content` has insite an entire html page with `<headers><aside> and <sections>`

I have the following code

```
if( empty( $error )){
       echo "<h3>File generated</h3>";
       $my_file = 'index.html';
       if (file_exists($my_file)) {
            if(unlink($my_file)){
            };
            $new_file = 'index.html';
            $handle = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$new_file);
            $data = $content;
            fwrite($handle, $data);
            fclose($handle);

            echo "<a download='index.html' href='index.html'><b class='download'>Download</b></a>";
        } else {
            $new_file = 'index.html';
            $handle = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$new_file);
            $data = $content;
            fwrite($handle, $data);
            fclose($handle);
            echo "<a download='index.html' href='index.html'><b class='download'>Download</b></a>";
        }
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that file?

Comment: yes, the file is created but when i generate new file and click to download, the downloaded file is the first that was created. if i check in the content of new file on server its was updated.

Comment: If you manually delete file and then try to download file, do you get error or still can download it?

Comment: i still can download the file

Comment: I see two options: 1) file is somehow cached in browser's memory - try to clear it, refresh page with ctrl+f5. 2) Path to file you want to download is wrong- maybe download='index.html' is pointing to another index.html, not the one you write to? If none of my thoughts is correct I'll have to sleep with that problem and maybe I'll try tommorow. gl

Comment: none of your thoughts is correct. i've deleted browser cache and the issue continue. the file is created but the downloaded file is always the same, even after the cache is cleared
check the site here: bit.ly/1crrcif

Comment: Well, I've tried a few times and every time I got fresh changed version

Answer (score 0):

hi i think it's will be work if variable $content will be contain correct data and you have permission to read, update, create file. in code I use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function for minimize your code

```
if( empty( $error )){
    echo "<h3>File generated</h3>";
    $my_file = 'index.html';
    file_put_contents($my_file, $content);   
    echo "<a download='index.html' href='index.html'><b class='download'>Download</b></a>";
 }
```

UPDATE:
Are you sure that you have correctly generated content and the $content always contains different value?

Comment: yes, i checked the file manualy on server and allways contains diferent values

Comment: You can manually add something to file index.html and view changes on browser if you don't see changes maybe you its wrong file or url